# Upload Files using Dropzone JS with regular HTTP request NOT AJAX

Tags: httprequest, dropzone.js

Currently I am using Dropzone JS to upload files to server along with some form data. here dropzone JS uploads all form data using ajax request. but i want to send data using regular http request. How can i achieve this ?

**Update**

Actually i want to perform some redirection based on few conditions after submitting form data along with files. So i need regular HTTP request. i tried `autoProcessQueue` but no use becuase after submitting , Dropzone is using `XMLHttp` request to send data.

Comment: What is so boring with de AJAX request? Have you tried to set [autoProcessQueue](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue) to `false`? Then you should be able to send the file to the server only when the user submits the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**DROPZONE doesn't support regular HTTP file upload.**

Here is the [issue on github](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/issues/741).

Comment by Author [enyo](https://github.com/enyo) is : `No. But you can listen to the success event and redirect the page after it uploaded`